# how to switch to another revision in svn without 'merging' files

Tags: eclipse, svn

When I do a switch to another revision number command, `svn` makes weird changes in file ("`<<<<<<< .mine`" thing)

For example in case of `xml`:

```
<<<<<<< .mine
    <TEST>hi</TEST>
    <blah>sss</blah>
=======
>>>>>>> .r14827
    <TEST2>yo</TEST2>
```

How to just switch to another revision with overwriting existing files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got merge on `svn up` **only** in case of **uncommited local changes**. Merge *conflicts* means that your changes can not be merged with update changes automatically and require human intervention

> How to just switch to another revision with overwriting existing files?

Commit changes before changing content (which happens on update) of your WC